# What happens when I create a custom object with Name field = NULL?

Tags: custom-object

I have an application where there is a custom object `Sales_Order__c`.

- The Name field is defined as Text , not AutoNumber
- There is Apex that creates this object and inserts as follows:

  ```
  Sales_Order__c so = new Sales_Order__c();
  insert so;
  ```

This works fine - I thought the Name field would be required. Apparently, the Name field is populated with the recordId.

Subsequent transactions insert other Sales Orders and occasionally, they violate duplicate checks. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First per the doc on *[Custom_Object__c](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_custom_object__c.htm)*, if inserted via the API, the `Name` field becomes the record's Id

> When the object is created using an API update() call, and the Name field is null, Salesforce sets the value to the record ID. **When the object is created using an API create() call, Salesforce sets the initial value to the record ID**. You can’t set the Name field to null.

Although the doc here doesn't say so, this applies to DML from Apex (and presumably Flow, I did not check)

The record Id is the **15** character Id - this is a case sensitive Id as that explains the duplicates

For example, in the org on

- Day 1, a Sales_Order__c was created with Name = `a108Z00000aixfn`
- Day 2, a Sales_Order__c was created with Name = `a108Z00000aixFn`

The Apex/SOQL-based dup checking uses case insensitive matching and since the two Name field differ only in the penultimate character `f` vs. `F`, the code thought the records were dups. Had duplicate checking been done with exact Matching Rules, the two recs would not be dups.

If for whatever reason your org allows custom objects to be inserted with null `Name` fields, be sure to coerce an update event so you can use a before save Flow or trigger to change the Name value to the 18 character Id. *You can't do this before insert as the Name has not yet been assigned*

Alternatively robustify your Apex code to do string compares that are case sensitive.