# How to Edit or Override Success Messages

Tags: pagemessages

I have some custom objects that are displaying a default success message when the record is created or updated. The default message is displaying **"Review a0GDn000001NLLJMA4 was saved"**. Where can I go to change this message so it replaces the object Id with the object name? Can this be done declaratively?

Comment: see this q&a - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/394539/what-happens-when-i-create-a-custom-object-with-name-field-null/394540#394540

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an AUTO NUMBER for RECORD NAME field and do not pass Name field while creating the record Salesforce populate ID field in the Name, I think those records are created through API or some APEX code.

You need to update the Name Field of those records also update the process of creating records. If Name field is meaningless for that object. please use AUTO NUMBER instead of text [image]

Comment: The Name field for this object is already set to Auto Number. I tried changing it to Text but then it becomes a required field that I cannot deselect in the page layout. So I changed it back to Auto Number. I need track down the logic so I can change it there.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should have an auto number field on the object
2- The auto number field must be on the page layout that fire the action